# How to put facebook like button in and customize it with different colors wordpress

Tags: facebook-like

I'm just wondering is it possible to customize the facebook like button with different colors other than the usual? I would also want to know how to properly implement the code without using a javascript? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The facebook like button is an image so you would need to actually edit the image to what you want. If you are using a generic link to "like" then you could alter that link with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook like button is implemented through IFRAME on different domain. I guess it's safe to say that you cannot change it. You can only select from the two options facebook has provided. The light and dark color.

for your concern about [how to implement facebook like button, here's a comprehensive how to guide.](http://www.bendaggers.com/how-to-add-facebook-like-twitter-tweet-google-plus-one-and-pinterest-pin-it-button-in-your-index-file-multiple-blog-posts-in-wordpress/,)

:)